# How to automate sending Loop component to Team Channel using python?

Tags: python, loops, webhooks, channel

I am using webhook connector to automate sending message to Teams Channel. If I want to send Loop component(for eg checklist content) instead of payload["text"] type, how can I json.dumps that body part?
r = self.http.request('post', f'{self.hookurl}', body= json.dumps(payload["text"]).encode('utf-8'), headers={'Content-Type:"application/json"}, timeout= 60).

I tried to get source code of loop component in html, but no idea how to paste that as correct payload to send through hook request.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.